# Lost changes because Git stash pop failing to complete

Tags: git, git-stash

I stashed changes in my local repo because I needed to pull and sync my code base. Stashing complained that one of the files (a database) was open. I reverted the open file to original state. Because of this, my stash got messy and now its not popping. I have a lot of important changes lost in the stash which is not popping back.

Here is output for 'git stash list':

```
    stash@{0}: WIP on master: f6e6d35 - Added Cabinet Raspi app initial version - Improved Muxboard module - Added NFC sample python module with support material
```

Here is output for 'git stash pop':

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        website/nokienv/Lib/site-packages/pip/__init__.py
        website/nokienv/Lib/site-packages/pip/__main__.py
        website/nokienv/Lib/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py
        website/nokienv/Lib/site-packages/pip/_internal/build_env.py
        website/nokienv/Lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor/ipaddress.py
        website/nokienv/Lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/__about__.py
        w
Aborting
```

The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.

```
Index was not unstashed.
```

Using command 'git stash pop --index 0' results in the same output with an extra message saying:

Can someone please help me retrieve the changes I have lost in the stash? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following command helped me in above situation:

git checkout stash -- .

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean your working directory first before `git stash pop` since there are conflects. Here are three solutions:

1. Discard local changes by `git reset --hard`.  (DANGER: current changes will be lost)
2. Stash local changes first and then pop the previous one:

```
    git stash 

    git stash pop stash@{1}
```

3. Commit local changes, and then stash pop and resolve the conflicts:

```
    git commit -m "xxx"

    git stash pop
```

Then some conflicts will appear and reslove it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you Nano, in fact I figured that my problem was solved with another method where I checkedout from stash with the following command:

git checkout stash -- .